# 2 NIC 2 Gateways one router one internet gateway

Tags: router, linux-networking, nic, iproute2

I have a router with two nets

eth0: 192.168.1.0/24, default gateway is 192.168.1.1

eth2: 10.0.88.0/24, default gateway is 10.0.88.1

Both networks use Gateway 192.168.2.1 to the Internet being connected to the router via third interface. All servers from both nets having one Nic each can ping any address properly.

I need now to set up a few ubuntu servers with 2 Nics, one leg in each net (eno1 in 192.168.1.0 and eno4 in 10.0.88.0). Consequently I have used iproute2 and have the following config:

```
ip route show
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eno1 onlink
10.0.88.0/24 dev eno4  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.88.11
192.168.1.0/24 dev eno1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.14
```

and

```
ip route show table mng
default via 10.0.88.1 dev eno4 
10.0.88.0/24 dev eno4  scope link  src 10.0.88.11
```

The rules are set as follows

```
ip rule show
0:  from all lookup local 
32760:  from all to 10.0.88.11 lookup mng
32761:  from 10.0.88.11 lookup mng 
32762:  from all lookup main
32763:  from all lookup default
```

I have furthermore set my rp_filter to 1 for all networks/nics.

Now to the question:
I can successfully ping the default gateways on both interfaces.

I can successfully ping my Internet gateway from the eno1 network

```
ping 192.168.2.1
PING 192.168.2.1 (192.168.2.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.572 ms
(...)
```

but I can NOT ping the Internet gateway from the eno4 network:

```
ping -I eno4 192.168.2.1
PING 192.168.2.1 (192.168.2.1) from 10.0.88.11 eno4: 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.88.11 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

This also what the command confirms:

```
ip neigh show
(...)
192.168.2.1 dev eno4  FAILED
(...)
```

What do I need to configure that eno4 can also reach my gateway to the internet (and any other internet address) via its default gateway?

Thank you very much in advance for any answer

Best regards

br

Comment: To confirm, can you ping both 192.168.1.1 and 10.0.88.1 from eno4?

Comment: For info, if you are wanting to turn rp_filter off, it should be set to 0. You would only need to do that however if you expected the ICMP replies to arrive on eno1 rather than eno4.

Comment: I think you also have to add `oif` and `iif` rules. `ip rule add oif en04 table mng` and `ip rule add iif en04 table mng`. Also ensure that the gateway with address `192.168.2.1` has a route to the `10.0.88.0/24` network.

Comment: @MarkoPolo: No, I can only ping 10.0.88.1 as Gateway from eno4; this is as it is wanted

Comment: @MarkoPolo
This was my suspicion too, but no evidence that ICMP packages are not coming back: Interesting wise, eno4 sends an arp request for 192.168.2.1 which is never answered instead of imp pings...

Comment: @Thomas Not sure that I understand you correctly: In my router 192.168.2.1 is the default gateway. What will oif and iif will do?

Answer (score 0):

There are two points to consider, as long as I got it right.

1. Your main gateway at `192.168.2.1` needs to know how to access the `10.0.88.0/24` and `192.168.1.0/24` networks.
   This can be established either by using `iptables` and `masquerading` on the router with the two nets, or with plain routing tables.
   In case of `masquerading`, your gateway at `192.168.2.1` will only receive packets from the router ( with the two nets ) of the third interface ( `192.168.2.???` ) because addresses are rewritten and everything works well.
   If you are not using `masquerading`, then your gateway at `192.168.2.1` will get packets from `192.168.1.0/24` and `10.0.88.0/24` directly. If your gateway at `192.168.2.1` does not have routes to these subnets, then it will select the default route.
   So this depends on your configuration on the router with the two nets.
2. On your Ubuntu servers, the `default via 10.0.88.1 dev eno4` entry in the `mng` table should be sufficient. 
   Then you need to tell the routing rule to use `mng` for traffic that is received from the `10.0.88.0/24` subnet.

   ```
   ip rule add from 10.0.88.0/24 table mng
   ```

   Next, add a rule to use the `mng` table for anything that should leave `eno4`.

   ```
   ip rule add oif eno4 table mng
   ```

Comment: Thanks Thomas!! The last rule with eno4 (I think this was meant with ens11) made the trick. It works now!

Comment: Ah, right. The `ens11` was the interface of my VM. Sorry for that. Updated the answer.